# Why solution with DENSE_RANK() is considered wrong answer?

Tags: sql, mysql, dense-rank

Here is the problem statement;

Write a SQL query to rank scores. If there is a tie between two scores,
both should have the same ranking. Note that after a tie,
the next ranking number should be the next consecutive integer value.
In other words, there should be no "holes" between ranks.

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Score |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 3.50  |
| 2  | 3.65  |
| 3  | 4.00  |
| 4  | 3.85  |
| 5  | 4.00  |
| 6  | 3.65  |
+----+-------+
```

For example, given the above Scores table,
your query should generate the following report
(order by highest score):

```
+-------+---------+
| score | Rank    |
+-------+---------+
| 4.00  | 1       |
| 4.00  | 1       |
| 3.85  | 2       |
| 3.65  | 3       |
| 3.65  | 3       |
| 3.50  | 4       |
+-------+---------+
```

Here is my solution which is considered **wrong**

```
SELECT
    score,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score DESC) AS rank
FROM scores;
```

Here is a recommended solution which is considered **correct**

```
SELECT s1.Score, (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Score)
    FROM Scores S2
    WHERE S1.Score <= S2.Score
    ) AS "RANK"
FROM Scores s1
ORDER BY s1.Score DESC;
```

Initially, I tried using the DENSE_RANK() function, and the query below produced the expected result. However, I received feedback stating that this solution was considered incorrect. I am now seeking clarification on why the DENSE_RANK() solution was deemed incorrect and if there are any specific requirements or constraints that need to be considered for the ranking.

Can anyone please help me understand the issue with the DENSE_RANK() solution?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Was this an automated test or something reviewed by a human being? And is the version of MySQL specified? Because DENSE_RANK was only added to MySQL in version 8 and so a lower specified version or an automated test that hasn't been updated may reject an otherwise valid answer.

Answer (score -1):

> I guess I am not adding any value here but trying to correct my
> response earlier due to misread.

The DENSE_RANK() solution you initially provided is indeed correct for the given problem statement. It correctly assigns ranks to the scores and handles ties appropriately. There is no issue with using DENSE_RANK() in this scenario.

```
SELECT
    score,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) AS rank
FROM scores;
```

The alternate solution using a subquery to count distinct scores might also achieve the desired result (might not be an optimum solution in some cases). However, it is not necessary in this case, as the DENSE_RANK() function can handle ties and produce the expected output.

```
SELECT s1.Score, (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Score)
    FROM Scores S2
    WHERE S1.Score <= S2.Score
    ) AS "RANK"
FROM Scores s1
ORDER BY s1.Score DESC;
```

Comment: Apologies for my response. I misunderstood and replied this way. What you are saying is correct. Trying to correct my response.

Comment: Using AI without actual expertise in the field seldom gives good results. Consider only using AI as an assistant for your own answer as opposed to being just a proxy.